# Is it possible to authenticate a mobile app with SameSite=Strict cookies?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, mobile, capacitor

My app is absolutely security critical.
I finished building its web version with SameSite=Strict cookies.
Now that I'm building its mobile version I can't seem to make the cookies work.

I was expecting a seamless cross-platform cookie experience, but from a mobile perspective the origin is "http://localhost" and not "https://my-website.com". Are mobile apps limited to SameSite=None cookies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a custom hostname by setting this preference in your config.xml

```
 <preference name="hostname" value="my-website.com" />
```